# Help link on Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, help

Is [Help](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?err=1&id=replacing_online_help.htm&siteLang=en_US) link available on salesforce1.If so where do I need to customize it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was raised in a recent **Dreamforce 2013** session [Building Help and Training to Make Every User an Expert](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuzllsUT2OQ&list=PLDZ5gCc7Mued_ed-_HvH2ciktRcpNNM80&index=8) i took part in. The answer is currently no, there is no help link support in Salesforce1. You can review the full answer given yourself at this [point](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZuzllsUT2OQ&list=PLDZ5gCc7Mued_ed-_HvH2ciktRcpNNM80&index=8) in the video recording, the question is hard to hear but is basically the same as this one...